# Machine Learning on encrypted Data

Tags: encryption, go, machine-learning

I want to implement a machine learning model (KNN or random forest) with GO, on encrypted data.

My data is encrypted with HElib (homomorphic encryption), means that i still can perform ADD & MUL on the encrypted data.

**My question is:** Do i have to re implement all the Machine Learning algorithm with GO, or can i use a bit of "golearn" lib?

Example of KNN implementation with GO using golearn lib:

```
rawData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("../datasets/iris_headers.csv", true)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

//Initialises a new KNN classifier
cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("euclidean", "linear", 2)

//Do a training-test split
trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(rawData, 0.50)
cls.Fit(trainData)

//Calculates the Euclidean distance and returns the most popular label
predictions, err := cls.Predict(testData)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(predictions)

// Prints precision/recall metrics
confusionMat, err := evaluation.GetConfusionMatrix(testData, predictions)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get confusion matrix: %s", err.Error()))
}
fmt.Println(evaluation.GetSummary(confusionMat))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own, decrypting version, of the base csv package;
https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/blob/master/base/csv.go

You could then pass the rawData output from your customer `ParseCSVToInstances` function to the KNN functions `InstancesTrainTestSplit` as normal.

Comment: @LieHili - One addition, and being unclear of your circumstances, it is always great to try to make the changes you need as a fork/pull request of the base project. Maybe someone else can get value from your changes too.

Comment: Did you implement this?